# Access to an array in a collection as a string list in flutter using a model

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called access using the client's id a the document id and a list of ids called sites in an array.

I want to access the list of ideas in sites, using a model and store them in a list of string. the list will be different lengths depending on the sites each client has so I just want a list of the ids back, I can not get this to work. Where I am at, is I can store the data and if I print it I can see the ids however when I  try to use them below it is not being able to see them.

If I manually insert a string list it all works, so I am guessing it is how I am working with the array.

Any help with this would be great! I am still a novice, Thank you

This is the model I am using

```
class Access {
  List<String> sites = List<String>();
  Access({this.sites});

  Access.fromJson(Map <String,dynamic>parsedJson,)
  : sites = (parsedJson["sites"] as List)?.map((e) => e as String)?.toList();

}
```

And this is where I am using it to only get the data for the ids within sites

```
QuerySnapshot document = await companySiteCollection.where(FieldPath.documentId,whereIn:**access.currentAccess.sites** ).getDocuments();
          document.documents.forEach((doc){
          Sites sites = Sites.toJson(doc.data, doc.documentID);
           _sitesList.add(sites);
           print(" ${_sitesList.length.toString()} database print");
          });
          siteNotifier.siteList = _sitesList;
        
        }
```

Comment: are you willing to get the whole collection and access it as an array, or are you storing an aarray in each document in firestore?

Comment: Hi, I am storing an array in each client document  in firestore with the sites they have access to

Comment: could you share the data structure so its more undestandable?